# XSLT lookup using regex

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a large xsl:choose (i.e. ~100) where the xsl:when is testing using a regex. I'm looking for a cleaner way, can this be replaced with a lookup table? This is just a sample of my code looks like today

```
<xsl:when test="matches($seq4, '^\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+/NCell:.+$', 'i')"> 
<xsl:value-of select="'NEIGHBOR'"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when   test="matches($seq4, '(/ULoCell:NodeB Function Name=.*, Local Cell ID=.*)', 'i')">
<xsl:value-of select="'SECTOR'"/>
</xsl:when>
```

I appreciate the help and I think I can make the Map sample code work if I make it a separate XML file and use import or include. I'm just wonder how difficult it would be to convert this into a document lookup. I'm familiar with document lookup and keys, but I have no idea how I would code the lookup using a regex? I Have the following lookup document:

```
<Telsa xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Row Key1="^[A-Z0-9]+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*/CnOperator:CnOperatorId=[0-9]+$" ElementType="CELL_CORE_OPERATOR" RegexReplace="&apos;^([A-Z0-9]+)/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*/CnOperator:(CnOperatorId=[0-9]+)&apos;, &apos;$1/CELL:$2/$3&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=[0-9]+, Cell.*$" ElementType="CELL" RegexReplace="&apos;^\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=([A-Z0-9]+), Local Cell ID=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=([0-9]+), Cell.*$&apos;, &apos;$1/Cell:$2&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+/EthernetInterface:Ethernet Interface No.=.*$" ElementType="EthernetInterface" RegexReplace="&apos;^(\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+)/EthernetInterface:Ethernet Interface No.=([0-9]+)$&apos; , &apos;$1/No=$2&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^[A-Z0-9]+/CELL:Local cell identity=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*/OPERATOR:CnOperatorId=[0-9]+$" ElementType="CELL_CORE_OPERATOR" RegexReplace="&apos;^([A-Z0-9]+/CELL:)Local cell identity=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*/OPERATOR:(CnOperatorId=[0-9]+)&apos; , &apos;$1$2/$3&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^[A-Z0-9]+/Cell:Local cell identity=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*, eNodeB identity=[0-9]+$" ElementType="CELL" RegexReplace="&apos;^([A-Z0-9]+/Cell:)Local cell identity=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*, eNodeB identity=[0-9]+$&apos;, &apos;$1$2&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^[A-Z0-9]+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=[0-9]+$" ElementType="CELL" RegexReplace="&apos;^([A-Z0-9]+)/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=([0-9]+)$&apos;, &apos;$1/Cell:$2&apos;"></Row>
  <Row Key1="^[A-Z0-9]+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=[0-9]+$" ElementType="CELL" RegexReplace="&apos;^([A-Z0-9]+)/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=([0-9]+), Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=([0-9]+)$&apos;, &apos;$1/Cell:$2&apos;"></Row>
</Telsa>
```

I would define the lookup with

```
<xsl:key name="table-lookup" match="Row" use="@Key1"/>
<xsl:variable name="LookupDoc" select="document('Telsa.xml')/Telsa"/>
```

How do I code the key lookup though?

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('table-lookup', $curr_key, $LookupDoc)/@ElementType"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following is what you are looking for, it stores the regular expressions, flags, and result in an XML structure and then looks up the first matching element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="pattern-map" as="element(map)*">
        <map pattern="^\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+/NCell:.+$" flags="i">NEIGHBOR</map>
        <map pattern="(/ULoCell:NodeB Function Name=.*, Local Cell ID=.*)" flags="i">SECTOR</map>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pattern-map[matches(current(), @pattern, @flags)][1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run against

```
<root>
    <item>a-b-c-1/NCell:x</item>
    <item>/ULoCell:NodeB Function Name=x, Local Cell ID=.y</item>
</root>
```

the output is

```
<root>
    <item>NEIGHBOR</item>
    <item>SECTOR</item>
</root>
```

Be careful if your regular expressions contain curly braces `{` or `}` as with a literal result element like `<map pattern="\w{2}" flags="i">foo</map>` this would be interpreted as an attribute value template so you would need to double them as in `<map pattern="\w{{2}}" flags="i">foo</map>`.

Comment: The only disadvantage of this is that an implementation of matches() might be more efficient if the regular expression is known statically, that is, if it is written as a string literal within the function call,

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution, the only other question is can this logic be placed into an external document much like the lookup table?

Comment: You have posted what looks like a comment as an answer. If you are referring to my answer, I have made the `pattern-map` a global parameter that can be passed in to the stylesheet before running the transformation. If you want to use an external document then it might be easier to change the type of the parameter to be a document but in general, as long as a global parameter is used, you can maintain the mapping outside of the XSLT code.

Comment: How difficult would it be to turn this into a document lookup instead of the Map lookup. Reason I'm asking is it easier for me to export the the data.